# Where did the word "brat" in reference to a spoiled child originate?

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english

I've heard that the etymology is unknown as the original word refers to a garment and the old English word *bratt* a cloak. None of these seem to point to how it came to be used derogatorily.

Answer (score 4):

**brat** [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/brat#etymonline_v_17063)

> c. **1500**, "beggar's child" ("... wyle beggar with thy brattis ...)

and the derogative/contempt sense:

> a. ‘A child, so called in contempt’ (Johnson). In 16th and 17th
>   centuries sometimes used without contempt, though nearly always
>   implying insignificance; the phrase beggar's brat has been common from
>   the first.[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22756?rskey=C8brqa&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

From Partridge:

> brat noun
>
> a child, especially a troublesome junior; a baby UK, **1505**
>
> Dalzell, Tom. The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional
>   English, 2nd Edition.

This latter suggests an early usage sense of contempt. From aprons, rags, beggars children, the derogative meaning appears to have come early.

Comment: If you're going to just quote stuff as an answer, you should attempt to use it to actually address the OPs concern about the meaning transfer: "OE 'bratt' cloak, which is from a Celtic source (compare Old Irish bratt "cloak, cloth"). The _transferred_ meaning is perhaps from notion of 'child's apron.' " (in the etymonline entry). Of course the OP could well have already known all this and so this ads nothing (but that is the OPs fault for not saying so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why should I delete my comment?

Comment: @Mari-LouA -           The negative connotation is still the main sense of the term according to M-W - ***Brat***: disparaging : Child, 
specifically : *an ill-mannered annoying child*
a spoiled brat
b : *an ill-mannered immature person* - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brat

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure how lbf's answer renders my comment deletable.  You said I should delete my comment (you've deleted yours so it's hard to understand things). Can you explain why you think so many useful comments should be deleted (mine included)?

Comment: @Mitch comments are not supposed to be answers. There was more useful info in your comment and mine (now deleted) that is completely missing from Ibf's answer. Sorry Ibf but sometimes you miss the obvious.